# Can we have a separate tag for combinatory logic?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags

Background information: [Combinatory logic on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#:%7E:text=Combinatory%20logic%20is%20a%20notation,quantified%20variables%20in%20mathematical%20logic.)

Basically it is a model of computation closely related to lambda calculus, but using a fixed set of combinators instead of lambda abstraction. The most prominent form of this is SKI (or SK) combinator calculus, which is extensionally equivalent to lambda calculus and therefore is Turing-complete (essentially a Turing tarpit).

I've identified nine challenges that are directly related to combinatory logic.

- [Four challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=SKI+calculus+is%3Aq) mentioning "SKI calculus"
- [Four challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=combinatory+is%3Aq) mentioning "combinatory"
- [One](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/28758/78410) that is essentially BC calculus golf

Some of these are tagged [lambda-calculus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lambda-calculus), but it isn't directly relevant to lambda calculus per se. So, can we have a separate tag for combinatory logic?

Comment: [Here's another one that is basically a combinator golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/161172/56656).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes

I think this would be a useful thing to have. As outlined in the question, this isn't fully covered by [lambda-calculus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lambda-calculus), and is to [functional-programming](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming) what [calculus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus) (for example) is to [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math). Additionally, as the example programs are split across 3 different search terms (at least), this isn't something that can be easily grouped with a single search term. Finally, there are not a large number of applicable questions, so adding this tag is unlikely to cause any edit disruption.